# what is the url that I can use to access to a folder images in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Hey I have a problem with Spring boot what is the url that I can use in my controller for save images In a folder exist in : " resources/static/images "

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: If any of the answer have helped you please accept it to point out the correct solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the static resources by just appending the path of them inside the static/public folder to your base URL.

---

Example:

You have an image in the folder `src/main/resources/static/images/brand.png`, the URL for that would be `${host}/images/brand.png`.